# vba coding issue failure to add to worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hi my problem is when the code searches (i, 1) to find "Hello" it finds it but won't send it to WSS and the more I look the frustrated I get can someone help please

```
Sub AddSelection()

Dim WSD As Worksheet ' Sheet 1 as prices sheet
Dim WSW As Worksheet ' Workings sheet as Information
Dim WSS As Worksheet ' Selections worksheet

Set WSD = Worksheets("Selection")
Set WSW = Worksheets("Workings")
Set WSS = Worksheets("Selections")

' Loop through records on WSD column A

FinalRow = WSD.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To FinalRow
        If WSD.Cells(i, 1) = "Hello" Then


        ' When I run the code this where the problem is
        WSD.Cells(i, 1).Copy Destination:=WSS.Cells(NextRow, 4)


        NextRow = NextRow + 2

        FinalRow = WSS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    End If
Next i

'Make sure WSR is the active sheet
WSS.Select


' Report that the macro is done
MsgBox prompt:=NextRow - 1 & " Results Records Are Copied To Worksheet."


End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

`NextRow` is never defined. You need to define it before using it.

To stop making this mistake, write this at the top of every "file" in your VBA project:

`Option Explicit`